# C# Regex Pattern Index for Multiple Patterns

Tags: c#, regex

```
// same pattern, but different look-aheads
// 'same' followed by 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'
string[] patterns = new string[]{
    "same(?=\\s*X)",
    "same(?=\\s*Y)",
    "same(?=\\s*Z)"
};

// replacements with respect to above patterns
string[] replacements = new string[]{
    "abc",
    "def",
    "ghi"
};

// now, I need to replace 'same' with a different
// string depending on the character after it
string input = "same X same Y same Z";
var regex = new Regex( string.Join("|", patterns) );
regex.Replace(input, m => replacements[m.PATTERN_INDEX]);
```

Is there something built in that will give me `PATTERN_INDEX` in the above code?

Note: I can't use a hash table lookup because I'm replacing the same pattern with different replacement strings depending on lookahead.

Comment: You mean you need to replace pattern1 wih abc and pattern2 with def? See http://ideone.com/q9ayK8

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628556/returning-only-part-of-match-from-regular-expression It might help you out here.

Comment: Please make your question clear, update it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew almost, except that I have more than 2 patterns. This was just an example.

Comment: @bitwise: Do you mean you have a regex with an alternation group and you want to know which *branch* matched? It is not possible. You need to enclose each branch into a separate capturing group and then check which group matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew updated code

Answer (score 1):

In my solution, I'm capturing X, Y and Z in three different capture groups (respectively the second, third and fourth; the first being the captured spaces).

Using call callback function (named CallBack), I'm looking in each groups to see which one have a value and replace with the proper text (either "abc", "def" or "ghi").

The key element here is the callback function. Sometime, to do very complicated replacement (like the conditional replacement in your question), you absolutely need to use a callback function.

Another key concept here is that the capture group return an empty string if they cannot match anything.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    string input = "same X same Y same Z";

    var myRegex = new Regex("same(\\s*)(?:(X)|(Y)|(Z))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string output = myRegex.Replace(input, Callback);

    Console.WriteLine(output);

static string Callback(Match match) {

    string toReturn = "";

    if (match.Groups[2].Value != "") {

        toReturn = "abc";

    } else if (match.Groups[3].Value != "") {

        toReturn = "def";

    } else if (match.Groups[4].Value != "") {

        toReturn = "ghi";
    }

    return toReturn + match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value + 
        match.Groups[3].Value + match.Groups[4].Value;
}
```

You can test it here: http://csharppad.com/gist/5c921d27cefad32a6d353a26a6906405

I haven't done C# for years and it took me quite sometime to write that simple code sample, so don't expect too much further help from me.

Good success

**EDIT**: I will write the algorithm in PHP since this is the language I used the most nowadays.

```
$test = new Test();

echo $test->callbackregex(
    '/same(\s*)(?:(X)|(Y)|(Z))/i',
    array(
        2 => array('abc', '$1' ,'$2'),
        3 => array('def', '$1' ,'$3'),
        4 => array('ghi', '$1' ,'$4')
    ),
    "same X same Y same Z"
);

class Test
{
    private $replacement = array();

    public function callbackregex($regex, array $replacement, $input)
    {
        $this->replacement = $replacement;

        return preg_replace_callback(
            $regex, 
            array($this, "callback"),
            $input
        );
    }

    private function callback($matches)
    {
        $toReturn = "";
        $total = count($matches);

        //I skip 0 because it is the overall match of the regex
        for($index = 1; $index < $total; $index++) {

            if (!empty($matches[$index]) and isset($this->replacement[$index])) {

                $replacementArray = $this->replacement[$index];

                if (is_string($replacementArray)) {

                    $replacementArray = array($replacementArray);
                }

                foreach ($replacementArray as $replacement) {

                    if (preg_match('/^\$\d+$/', $replacement)) {

                        $i = (int) str_replace('$', '', $replacement);

                        if (isset($matches[$i])) {

                            $toReturn .= $matches[$i];
                        }

                    } else {

                        $toReturn .= $replacement;
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        return $toReturn;
    }
}
```

Test: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85a5547c7194b36c763a0f8dc7672e5785ec2044

Comment: Thanks, but while this will probably work, it's quite a bit more complicated than just using 3 separate regex searches.

Comment: Finally though, after searching some more myself, I don't think that such built-in features exists, even though its definitely feasible, and even reasonable to expect it, when you can pass several patterns at once.

Comment: If you can find a way so the callback function would not be static (they are not un PHP), you could put your replacement array in a class variable and access it within the function. Instead of static replacement, loop in the match array to find which index is not empty and match it with the exact same index in the replacement array (test if if exists, otherwise replace with an empty string).

Comment: I edited my answers with a PHP code sample. This should give you a good idea how to implement what you want. Test it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85a5547c7194b36c763a0f8dc7672e5785ec2044