# Regex to match stringbetween nth(5th) and nth(6th) iterations of a character

Tags: regex

Good afternoon - I've been searching all morning to find a way to has this expression together and haven't had much luck so I'm coming to the community....

I have a log file that contains tens of thousands of lines of which I need to extract the string between the 5th and 6th iteration of the "," separator. Here is the string:

Line 2850: Line 67563: BunchOfText,BunchOfText:BunchOfText,46.2,11637,42.2,2512,1516

I need to get the value "2512" out of this string.
This is what I'm using now but NotePad++ Wants to capture everything up TO the 5th "," but RegEx buddy says this works:

`^(?:[^,]*\,){5}([^,]*)`

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/CLq9tS/1)?

Comment: It sounds like Regex Buddy is operating in multiline mode (`^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each line, while Notepad++ is not (`^` and `$` will match the beginning and end of the full string). I don't use Notepad++ but my guess is that it has an option to enable multiline. It may also be possible to enable this mode by putting `(?m)` at the beginning of your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be answered by another question asked here. Here is a link and the excerpt 
Stolen from solution [Returning only part of match from Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628556/returning-only-part-of-match-from-regular-expression)

---

*You could also try the concept of "lookaround". This is a kind of zero-width assertion, meaning it will match characters but it won't capture them in the result.
In your case, we could take a positive lookbehind: we want what's behind the target string "firstname.surname" to be equal to "User Name:".
Positive lookbehind operator: (?<=StringBehind)StringWeWant*

---

so i think for your solution you can use  (?<=*.,*.,*.,*.,*.,)*[^,]

i didnt get to try the final answer i suggested, but i hope you got the idea :D

i think u r looking for ?<= rather ?: